# UIImageView shadow not being drawn first time cell is visible

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with a customCell which has an UIImageView that I'm adding shadow to. However, the shadow is not being drawn before the cell has been "outside" the visible collection view and comes back into (UICollection)view.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"genreCell";

GenreViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.genreImageView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.5;
cell.genreImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, -1);
cell.genreImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
cell.genreImageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

cell.genreImageView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:cell.genreImageView.bounds].CGPath;

return cell;

}
```

Comment: @MarcusAdams Yes, but no luck.

Comment: Is there a reason you are setting the shadowPath property? Since you want to set the shadow to the bounds of the image view itself, you shouldn't have to do that. Try removing that line.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook Now it works right away, but lags A LOT. It did not lag at all before with the shadowPath property. I read that it increased performance.

Comment: try adding `cell.genreImageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;` and `cell.genreImageView.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];` This renders the shadow as a bitmap and should eliminate your lag.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook I can't believe that I didn't think of that.. Make it an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason you are setting the shadowPath property? Since you want to set the shadow to the bounds of the image view itself, you shouldn't have to do that. Remove that line.

Also, to prevent lag:

```
cell.genreImageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
cell.genreImageView.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

Answer (score 4):

The bounds of the cell is not set the first time `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method is called. Therefore the `shadowPath` is not calculated correctly. Make sure you update the shadowPath whenever the bounds of the cell changes. `layoutSubviews` method of `GenreViewCell` can be used for that.